# webview is not showing last few lines of statically created html string using loadDataWithBaseUrl()

Tags: android, webview

I want to display the static html string in webview but I am not able to scroll till the last line of string. I have debugged the code the data is coming fine but webview simply doesnt show last 2/3 lines. Please go through my code below
1) xml file

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".QuestionBankActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orangewood"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"

            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/abc"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="334dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/orangewood" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveNextBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:onClick="forword_to_next_ques"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/saveNext"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:text=" A"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text=" B"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text=" C"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text=" D"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/saveNextBtn"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/saveNextBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="147dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:onClick="Clear_Response"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/clearResponse"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reviewBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:onClick="mark_for_review_Next"
        android:text="@string/mark_for_review_Next"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) I am using webview like this in activity

```
WebView wb1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb1.setInitialScale(0);
        wb1.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        wb1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb1.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        String header = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" +
                "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
                "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"jqmath-0.4.0.css\">    " +
                "<script src=\"jquery-1.4.3.js\"></script>" +
                "   <script src=\"jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js\"></script>" +
                "</head><body background=\"white\" text=\"black\">";
        String footer = "</body></html>";
        StringBuilder question = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder opt1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder opt2 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder opt3 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder opt4 = new StringBuilder();

        //Get the Option from db
        opt1.append(ques.getOption1());
        opt2.append(ques.getOption2());
        opt3.append(ques.getOption3());
        opt4.append(ques.getOption4());


        String allOptions = "<ol type=\"A\"> <li>"+opt1+"</li><li>"+opt2+"</li><li>"+opt3+"</li><li>"+opt4+"</li></ol>";
        question.append(header);
        //TextView qno = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qnoTextView);
        //qno.setText(next_counter+")");
        question.append("Question No. "+ques.getQno()+"<br><hr>");
        question.append(ques.getQuestion());

        //String image_path = ques.getImgPath();
        String image_path = ques.getImgPath();
        if(!image_path.equals(""))
        {
            String diagram  = "<img src="+"\""+image_path+".png\" height=\"60%\" width=\"100%\" alt=\"Img cannot be displayed!!\"/>";
            question.append(diagram);

        }

        //Append Options below question
        /*question.append(opt1);
        question.append("<br>"+opt2);
        question.append("<br>"+opt3);
         */
        question.append("<br>"+allOptions);


        question.append(footer);

        //  wb1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Empty.html");

        wb1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", question.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

3) Now if say my question is like this 
some text of 5-6 lines 
option1
option2
option3
option4

the whole options coming when i was debugging code. But the webview is showing only question then 2/3 options!
What am I doing wrong? some questions with even more lines in it shows perfectly fine and for some questions webview doesnt show last few lines!!!
Please help me in solving this issue I have googled much but I didnot find answer....
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Quick fix (might sound like `bullshit`, but it's just a **quick** fix): Simply append "<br/><br/><br/><br/>" to your HTML string. Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply!!

Comment: But, as I said, it's a quick fix, not a REAL SOLUTION. You should consider @PaulLammertsma's words as wiser than mine.

Comment: It is not bullshit it really works!!!

Comment: Glad that it helped (momentarily). But please consider reengineering your layout to make the WebView fit the available space ;)

Comment: I know my GUI is bad I am new to android just learning design part.Can you please share how to do that?

Comment: Noone borns already learned... This [page](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) and this [one](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined all your views with a fixed height. It's likely that the WebView is simply extending out of the layout.

I would suggest using the View Hierarchy tool to check if that is the case, and if so, [brushing up a little on your understanding of how views and layouts work](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts). Don't forget that devices have different shapes and sizes, and that your layout should cope with the screen real estate that it has.

(As an aside: you're not making things easier for yourself by nesting RelativeLayouts within each other and giving them names that suggest that they're LinearLayouts.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggessions:)                                           Actually I want to show UI like different sections for eg I want to show some buttons/textview/.. on top bar then webview below that and some buttons for navigation below webview. For this purpose I have used different layouts. I am new to android GUI. can you share any best article or tips for android beginners like me?

Comment: [Lars Vogel has a good generic getting started guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html). Android has an excellent training document for [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html), which is especially worth the short read.